# Wireguard server and client are able to ping each other but wireguard clients are unable to ping each other

Tags: networking, ping, nat, wireguard, nftables

I am setting up a Wireguard configuration where I have the following entities:

1. Remote VM instance on hosts such as google cloud or amazon aws. This
   is a remote client to my wireguard server. Let's call this `gcp_client`
2. A wireguard server on a machine hosted on my LAN. Lets call this `srvlan`.

- IPv4 forwarding is enabled on this device by `sysctl`.
- There is a Ubiquiti Edgerouter 4 between the WAN and my LAN. I have enabled port forwarding and hairpin NAT on this device. I have also set up a dynamic DNS on this router.

3. One or more clients on my LAN, which should be able to connect to the remote client as if it were a machine on my LAN. As I am facing the problem with my first client itself, let's call it `client1`.

In my setup, I am able to ping between `srvlan` and `gcp_client` both ways, and between `client1` and `srvlan` as well. However. pings from `gcp_client` to `client1` (and vice versa) fail.

Based on reading the results of `tcpdump -i wg0 -n icmp`, I made the following observations:

1. Pings from `client1` to `gcp_client` reach `srvlan` but are not forwarded to the router.
2. Pings from `gcp_client` to `client1` reach my router, which forwards them to `srvlan`. However the packets do not get forwarded by `srvlan` to `client1`.

The only thing I can conclude from this is that the forwarding rules on `srvlan` are somehow faulty. I am using `nftables` to manage this device.

This is my wireguard configuration; ip addresses and port number have been changed.

```
# wg0.conf for gcp_client
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.1.2/24
ListenPort = 50000
PrivateKey = gcp_client_privkey

[Peer]
PublicKey = srvlan_pubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.0/24
Endpoint = srvlan_ddns:50000

# wg0.conf for srvlan
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.1.1/24
ListenPort = 50000
PrivateKey = srvlan_privkey

[Peer]
PublicKey = gcp_client_pubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.2/32
Endpoint = gcp_client_domainname:50000
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = client1_pubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.3/32
Endpoint = client1_lanhostname:50000
PersistentKeepalive = 25 # I realise this one is unnecessary, but I had added it while testing just in case the problem got fixed.

# wg0.conf for client1
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.1.3/24
ListenPort = 50000
PrivateKey = client1_privkey

[Peer]
PublicKey = srvlan_pubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.0/24
Endpoint = srvlan_lanhostname:50000
```

This is my firewall on `srvlan`.

```
# nft list ruleset
table inet firewall {
        chain inbound {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state established,related accept
                ct state invalid drop
                iif "lo" accept
                ip protocol icmp accept
                ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
                ip protocol igmp accept
                tcp dport 22 accept
                iifname "eno1" tcp dport { 80, 443 } ct state new accept
                iifname "eno1" udp dport 50000 ct state new accept
                iifname "wg0" udp dport 53 ct state new accept
                iifname "wg0" tcp dport { 80, 443 } ct state new accept
                iifname "wg0" udp dport 50000 ct state new accept
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state established,related accept
                ct state invalid drop
                iifname "wg0" oifname "eno1" ct state new accept
        }

        chain outbound {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                ct state invalid drop
        }
}
table ip router {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname "eno1" ip saddr 10.0.1.0/24 masquerade
        }
}
```

Comment: Why does srvlan have `Endpoint` for each peer? Aren't peers connecting to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *srvlan* forwards WireGuard-tunneled traffic, it receives it from *wg0* and routes it to... *wg0* again: twice the same interface.

So you need to append this entry to the *inet firewall forward* chain of *nftables*:

```
                iifname "wg0" oifname "wg0" accept
```

Other issues, in chain *inbound*:

---

> ```
>                 ip protocol icmp accept
>                 ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
>                 ip protocol igmp accept
> ```

While *protocol* works for IPv4, *nexthdr* in protocol IPv6 doesn't guarantee that the Next Header will be ICMPv6: there can be several [Extension Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) between the Fixed Header and the upper-layer protocol header. If such extension headers appear in some packets, then `nexthdr ipv6-icmp` won't match anymore. Use the correct syntax, for IPv4 and IPv6:

```
                meta nfproto ipv4 meta l4proto icmp accept
                meta nfproto ipv6 meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
                meta nfproto ipv4 meta l4proto igmp accept
```

Depending on the *nftables* version, it will be displayed back in a more simplified form.

---

> ```
>                 iifname "wg0" udp dport 50000 ct state new accept
> ```

The port 50000 doesn't appear inside the WireGuard interface (unless you want to tunnel WireGuard within WireGuard), but outside (for which there's already a rule). It shouldn't be needed.

---

Remember as you add more WireGuard clients/peers (as you did correctly), that there can't be overlaps in *srvlan*'s *AllowedIPs* entries since they determine the cryptorouting that happens in WireGuard to select the adequate peer, after the standard routing. Also, if *gcp_client* connects through *srvlan* to servers not using WireGuard tunnels, then their LAN address must also be added both to the *AllowedIPs* and the routing table of *gcp_client*. *AllowedIPs* is used both to accept a packet based on its source (and determine which peer and maybe update its endpoint in case of roaming), and to determine to which peer to send a packet based on its destination.

Comment: I had changed my forwarding rule to just `iifname wg0 accept` to make it work. Also I'd like to understand, when peer1 sends a packet to peer2, it is sent over the physical interface before being forwarded to the wireguard interface, right? Wouldn't I need forwarding rules to allow `physical<->wireguard` packet movement? Or will the inbound/outbound chains handle that?

Comment: From what I understand of your setup, the only place where you need physical<->wireguard movement is when gcp_client will reach a non-WireGuard destination. You already have a rule for this: `iifname "wg0" oifname "eno1"` and the reverse direction is handled by `... established ...`

Comment: While the packet *in* the tunnel is forwarded through srvlan, the packet used for the *envelope* is not forwarded: it's sent from peer1 to srvlan. Then an other is sent from srvlan to peer2. Those are subject to your inbound and outbound chains, not to the forward chain. Once this is configured correctly, the goal is to forget about it. The tunnel is just an interface and one has only to care about this interface, not how it's working anymore.

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense. So wireguard will only ask nftables for permission to route packets within the wireguard interfaces. Another thing I'd like to understand is would it require manual settings to allow forwarding between multiple wireguard interfaces on `srvlan` or is it possible to tell nftables to work with a specific interface type?

Comment: If you choose to use multiple WireGuard interfaces (not multiple peers on a single interface as you did here, this is specific to WireGuard and can't be told to nftables of course), and choose a naming convention: let them all start with `wg`, then in nftables you can use `iifname "wg*"` or `oifname "wg*"` to match them all.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just remembered that for recent enough versions of nftables and/or kernel, `iifkind "wireguard"` or `oifkind "wireguard"` can be used to match a wireguard interface whatever its name.